# How to get all files in that folder

Tags: php

Hello i have folder with some files inside and i want to create script inside in that folder.

Comment: You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php with `preg_match` as you iterate over the results, or you could try glob, that uses a different regex format. Also note `g` is not a modifier in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SPL for that:

```
$filesystem_iterator = new FilesystemIterator(".", FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS + FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME);
$filesystem_iterator = new RegexIterator($filesystem_iterator, "~backup_\\d{4}_\\d{2}_\\d{2}.zip~");
foreach ($filesystem_iterator as $pathname)
{
    var_dump ($pathname);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function named `glob()` which let's you find directories and files with a pattern: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php